# Authentication without email and password.

Tags: authentication

I am trying to have an authentication system for apis. But unlike traditional way, this will be **without email and password**

The front end is an android app. Initially the app will have empty auth_token in the local storage, now the app requests for 
an auth token from the server, by sending the mobile_number, device_id and gcm_id.

Now the server generates a `16 securerandom hex,` and sends it as auth token to the front end.

Now the front end has to call all the apis using this auth token.

The server user table will be like this

id || mobile_number || device_id || gcm_id || auth_token

**Question 1:**

Should I generate my auth token based on the mobile_number, device id or can it be independently generated?

**Question 2:**

Should the auth token be changed? or can I use the same auth token permanently for the user. If it has to be changed .. can you please guide me in pointing out which strategy to use

**Question 3:**

What are the pitfalls for this kind of authentication. I don't want the user to type the email and password, but at the same time want to identify the user for personalization calculations.

Comment: So if a user's telephone dies the access to their account is lost forever?

Comment: Yes as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication tokens are passwords. They should generally be designed to be handled by the client and server automatically with periodic rotation, to mitigate the risks of potential brute force attacks or credential leakage such as through a compromised user device or another server bug like Heartbleed. Make your tokens expire every so often, maybe 2 weeks or a month, and have the client app either require re-authentication when a token expires, or automatically make a request to refresh the token before it happens.

The user authentication scheme you're describing is for a device, not a user. You won't be able to identify one user from another reliably using those details, but that's not to say email+password is any better, it just comes with different usage expectations. You're identifying a mobile device by its device_id and adding some confidence that its owner hasn't changed by verifying the phone number. I'm not familiar with GCM so I'm not sure what property that adds. To add another factor of device authentication that is not so straightforward for another party to spoof, I suggest having your client app generate its own "something you know" password to use for requesting an initial token. That device-internal password can be its secret for authenticating with the service for purposes of automatic token issuance, and can be rotated more infrequently than the regular per-request auth token.

For both your client secret and your auth tokens, just like passwords you should aim to make them long and random. If the auth token is auto-rotating, you can allow for it to be much shorter without introducing realistic risks, to a degree. I'd say at least 16 random bytes even for a short-lived token should be the minimum, as 12 characters are within the realm of practical offline hash brute-forcing, and it's good to have a sizeable window of safety between what's plausible today and tomorrow's improvements in cracking capabilities.

It's important to remember that what you're describing will not authenticate a person, but simply an individual device. It sounds like that's what you intend to do for your project but it's important to understand the distinction and what it implies.

Answer (score -1):

Question 3: One pitfall is not encrypting the key wherever you store it.  If you store it in a database (User table, e.g.) you should encrypt with a method like this: https://saasbook.blogspot.com/2016/08/encrypting-application-level-data-at.html

Comment: So you mean to say auth_token has to be encrypted?

Comment: Usually it would be, but if you're not worried about them being used incorrectly then maybe not in your case.

Comment: what about mobile number and device id? they also should be encrypted?

Comment: All depends on if your worried about them being easily discovered and mis-used.

Comment: An authentication token is a type of password and should be stored using password storage best practices. This means using a one way hashing function such as bcrypt or pbkdf2, appropriately configured, and verified using a secure compare function. Reversible encryption provides a way to leak credentials with no distinct functional advantage in return.